# How to increase limits for processes created from fstab?

Tags: 14.04, mount, wine, fstab, fuse

I am using `ciopfs` in Ubuntu 14.04 to mount a case insensitive version of a game folder which is the target for a wine-based modding program.  Unfortunately, as the modding tool parses through all the files it causes a "too many open files error".

I have traced the fault back to the `ciopfs` process, which is stuck with the kernel default limits of 1024/4096.  I can get around this by increasing my limits in `/etc/security/limits.conf` and manually mounting with `ciopfs` after I log in, but this means the filesystem wont be listed in `/etc/fstab` and therefore won't be mounted at boot.

Does anyone know of a way to circumvent these limits while still using /etc/fstab?

Comment: Which user is `ciopfs` running as?

Comment: When mounted at boot from `/etc/fstab` its running as root with 1024/4096 limits.  I can start `ciopfs` with `sudo` and it also runs as root but with my increased limits from `/etc/security/imits.conf`, so it appears to be to do with *when* it is mounted, rather than which user it is mounted as.

Answer (score 0):

Interpose your own **mount helper**. Edit the 3rd field of the /etc/fstab entry from `ciopfs` to `myciopfs` then create the file `/sbin/mount.myciopfs` and do `chmod a+rx` on it.  This script will be executed by mount when you manually or automatically mount the entry.  It will pass most of the fstab line options to the script.

Write a shell script in the helper file to set a new ulimit and then execute the real `mount.ciopfs` helper. Eg:

```
#!/bin/bash
ulimit -n 5000       # maximum open files
exec /sbin/mount.ciopfs "$@"
```